# Error with PrettyPhoto in Gallery

Tags: prettyphoto

I hope someone can help me.
I'm doing a website that has a section in which a photo, a text description and a link to gallery, something like listed.

PHOTO - TEXT NARRATIVE PRODUCT 1
Link Gallery (2 photos)

PHOTO - TEXT NARRATIVE PRODUCT 2
Link Gallery (1 photos)

PHOTO - TEXT NARRATIVE PRODUCT 3
Link Gallery (0 photos)

and below the text I wish you a link that allows me to lift the PrettyPhoto and there additional photos are presented in the modal window.

The problem I have is that from the web administrator photos, record successfully, each photo on your record. But when I run the gallery of Product1, load 3 photos, 2 of our record:FOTO1 and FOTO2 ,but too FOTO 3 (product2)

Code

```
sqla="SELECT gallery_obra FROM subservicio WHERE id_servicio=   '{$data['id_servicio']}'";
```

//So much for the SQL gives me the photos of the register (id_servicio) I give him FOTO1; FOTO2

```
querya=mysql_query(sqla);
data01=mysql_fetch_assoc(querya);

if((strlen(data01['gallery_obra']))>3)

 {

images=explode(';',data01['gallery_obra']);
//So far this well because in the array visualize the names of the
  photos, according to Id. For example I have for product1

images [0] = FOTO1
images [1] = FOTO2

and product 2, I have
images [0] = FOTO3
```

// But when you run the PrettyPhoto already out something else.

```
foreach($images as $key => $value)

{
if($value!='')
{
   if($key==0)
   echo "<div style='text-align:right;width:94%;padding:10px;'><a   href='".SUBSERV_IMAG.$value."' rel='prettyPhoto[galeria]'><img src='images/vermas.png' border='0'></a></div>";
else
 echo "<a href='".SUBSERV_IMAG.$value."' rel='prettyPhoto[galeria]'><img src='".SUBSERV_IMAG.$value."' style='display:none;'></a>";
}
}
```

Where is the error?